# How to make two buttons make in one row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <a ui-sref="inspectionsBuilder.view.step3" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
                Previus <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-click="builderStep4.save(true)">Save and...</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-click="builderStep4.save()">Save</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here how it looks in view:

[image]

I need to make `Save` and `Save and` buttons in one row  ant put it on left side,like this:

[image]

I have some difficulty to implement it, any idea?

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/144/

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a similar demo here in **Snippet**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display twitter bootstrap btn-group inline with text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264897/display-twitter-bootstrap-btn-group-inline-with-text)

Answer (score 0):

Try to `.btn-group a {float:left;}`

Comment: It may be useful to add an explanation of what the statement does and why you've done it that way. It often makes it clearer to the questioner and in turn helps your answer get accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution with the code snippet you have provided,

https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/145/

I have removed the btn-block class and re-aligned the html so that it looks like your expectation.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="builderStep4.save()">Save</a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="builderStep4.save(true)">Save and...</a>
         <a ui-sref="inspectionsBuilder.view.step3" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
                Previus <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
            </a>
    </div>
</div>
```